# Filter Data View with SOAP Query as Source

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter, soap

I am creating a printable company directory. I have a SOAP Service query that pulls everyone's data from the search service.

The query returns all the results I want.

I have enabled the "Sort & Filter on Headers" option in SP Designer so that users can filter the list by office location, or department.

Sort works perfectly, however I get a "This column type cannot be filtered" error when I try to filter.

The columns that I am trying to filter are single line, text fields with no multiple values.

I have no idea why I cannot filter this.

This is all in SharePoint 2010.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have figured this out, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Check if any of your field has property "SPField.Filterable" set as false

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about checking that? I cannot find it anywhere.